Get Application object from Process
Hi does anyone know how to (or if its even possible) to get the application object from the Process/Process ID?
Our application uses Interopservices.Marchal to hook onto an application. This is working great but if you have more than one application open then it will always hook onto the first one. Below is the code:
oApp = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Inventor.Application")
There is a way to get the running processes using the code below but is there a way to get the application object from that process?
Dim App As Process() = Process.GetProcessesByName("Inventor")
Thanks!

This question is similar to: How to use Marshal.getActiveObject() to get 2 instance of of a running process that has two processes open. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
